# Continuous family of isometries on a Hilbert space shrinking to $0$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space. I would like to explicitly construct a family of bounded operators, $(W_t)_{t\in(0,1]}$, with each $W_t:H\rightarrow H$ being an isometry, with the following properties:

1. $W_t$ is continuous in the strong operator topology;
2. $W_1=id_H$;
3. $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}(W_t W_t^*)=0,$

where the limit is taken in the strong operator topology.

*Remark:* That it is possible to construct such a family $W_t$ is something I came across in a a paper, although the authors did not give a proof. I see that the infinite-dimensionality of $H$ must be important here, and the right idea seems to be to somehow construct $W_t$ so that the image of $W_t$ as a function of $t$ gets smaller as $t\rightarrow 0$. But it seems to be tricky to explicitly do this and also satisfy the continuity condition.

Comment: Which paper? Have you tried chasing down the references?

Comment: In point 3, in what sense are you taking the limit? It doesn't appear to be the strong operator topology, since, for any $x \in B_H$, we have $W_t x \in S_H$ and $W_t W_t^* W_t x = W_t x \in S_H$, so $\|W_t W^*_t\| \ge 1$ for all $t$.

Comment: What I meant by point 3 is that for any given $x$, $W_t W_t^* x\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow 0$. So in particular for $s\neq t$ we may not have $W_t W_t^* W_t x = W_t x$.

Comment: I don't know how to prove it, but I have some ideas. Try to deform the identity into the right shift operator first, with $T_1 = I$ to $T_2 = R$. Then, repeat this operation to deform $I = T_1 \to R = T_2 \to R^2 = T_3 \to \ldots$, and let $W_t = T_{1/t}$. To obtain this deformation, think about finite dimensions: how can you rotate $\Bbb{R}^n\times\{0\}$ to $\{0\}\times\Bbb{R}^n$ in a "nested" fashion, so that $\Bbb{R}^m\times\{0\}$ rotates to $\{0\}\times\Bbb{R}^m$ for $m<n$?

Comment: Actually can't we just use the linear homotopies between $I\rightarrow R$, $R\rightarrow R^2$ etc, and using your definition of $W_t$? More precisely, let $W_1=I, W_{1/2}=R,\ldots, W_{1/n}=R^{n-1}$. For $t\in[\frac{1}{2},1]$ define $W_t=(2t-1)W_1+(1-(2t-1))W_{1/2}$, etc.

Comment: You can't, no, as the resulting maps will not all be isometries. Indeed, if $S$ and $T$ are distinct isometries, then $Sx \neq Tx$ for some $x$, and $\|\lambda Tx + (1 - \lambda) Sx\| < \|x\|$ for all $\lambda \in (0, 1)$ by the strict convexity of the Hilbert Space ball.

Comment: @TheoBendit I think Adrian's answer below with the continuous version of the shift operator works. We almost had it :)

Comment: Haha, yep. Using functions rather than sequences is a smart idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify $H$ with $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+,dm)$, where $dm$ is the Lebesgue measure. Define the isometries $(R_s)_{s \in \mathbb{R}_+}$ by
$$
R_s(f)(t) = \begin{cases} f(t - s) & \mbox{ when } t \geq s\\
0 &\mbox{ otherwise }\end{cases}
$$
Then $R_0$ is the identity and $P_s = R_s \, R_s^\ast$ is the projection given by multipliying by $\chi_{[s,\infty)}$, therefore goes to $0$ in the SOT topology as $s \to \infty$. To obtain your $W_t$ just make a continuous change of variable sending $1$ to $0$ and $0$ to $\infty$.